# How can I mask a password in Swagger using Swashbuckle

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swashbuckle

We are using Swashbuckle on our API's, and for one of the metohds we are offering a login. How can the password be masked in Swagger UI?

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("text/plain")]
public async Task<string> Login(string userId, string password)
```

I have seen that appearantly Swagger supports a password fromat. However this is not C# code. I have no idea where to put this

```
@Parameter(schema = @Schema(type = "string", format = "password"))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can try to use `DataType` attribute with `DataType.Password` enum that put into we want to mask parameter.

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("text/plain")]
public async Task<string> Login(string userId,[DataType(DataType.Password)]
 string password)
```

Then we can get mask the parameter as below

[image]

This Modify might be worked after `v2.5.0` version which discusses from [Does not use DataType.Password #521](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/521)

**Note**: Using attribute and enum from namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`

Comment: The DataType annotation was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!